# How can I mount network drive on azure vm by using run command?

Tags: azure, automount

1. I use this PowerShell script on Run Command in azure VM page.
   [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrVx4.png)

> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName [name] -Port 445
>
> Invoke-Expression -Command "cmdkey /add:[path] /user:[username] /pass:[password]
>
> net use Y: \[path] /u:[username]

2. Return success
3. But when I enter the VM and found that error as below:
   [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCLxe.png)

I have no idea what wrong with that.
Does anyone encounter that problem, too?

Answer (score 0):

You mount drive using `net use` this has been an on going thing with Windows for a while.

Check the drive letter in `Command Prompt` or `Powershell`, if the mount command was successful it should be there.

Comment: Thanks for replying, But I am using that command on azure run command service,
It shows success but I cant see anything on my vm